# Replacing the href for my <a> links using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code to add `'target', '_blank'` for all my  links, as follow:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

var pollCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function($){
   checkCalendar($);
});

function checkCalendar($) {
   //stop after 10 seconds
   if (pollCount > 20)
      return;
   //if the calendar hasn't loaded yet, then wait .5 seconds
   if ($('.ms-acal-title a').length < 1) {
      pollCount++;
      setTimeout(function(){checkCalendar($);}, 500);     
   }
   else {
      //the calendar has loaded, so do work
      $('.ms-acal-title a' ).attr('target', '_blank');
    }
}    
</script>
```

the above code is working perfectly for me. but i want to do additional step, where i need to replace the url for all the `<a>` links as follow:-

1. currently the links will have a url as follow `https://*****/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=4`. where the ID will differ based on the item i am viewing.
2. now i want the url to be as follow `https://******/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=0579a0325489&ItemId=4`.

so how i can get the Id from the current url and create a new `href` for all my related `<a>` links?

Comment: get the `href` attribute value and replace it . No ?

Comment: `$('.ms-acal-title a' ).attr('href', 'newurl.com/somepath');` pretty sure thats all your asking about?

Comment: loop through all the a elements and replace the href attribute for each one with the relevant value. What have you researched? What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck with? We're not here to do basic research for you, or write all your code for you (not that it will be particularly complicated, but still). Please at least demonstrate that you made some effort on this, it's not difficult to think up the basic logic and then google for code samples of each step.

Comment: @akaBase but in my case i need to get the Id for each item separately .. so the new url will be different for each item `.attr('href', 'newurl.com/somepath');` ?? i think i need some sort of looping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the way you are setting the `target="_blank"`, the same way you can update the `href` something like

```
(this).attr("href", "newurlValue");
```

For example

```js
$("a").each(function() {

    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    var id  = $(this).attr("href").split("ID=")[1];
     
    $(this).attr("href", `newurlValue/itemId=${id}`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://test.com/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=4">Test4</a>
<a href="https://test.com/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=5">Test5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example for you to use as guidance:

```
let oldurl = 'https://*****/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=4';
let params = oldurl.split('=');
let newurl = 'https://******/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=0579a0325489&ID=' + params[1];
$('.ms-acal-title a' ).attr('href', newurl);
```

Just notice that you may need to adapt the `split` part to your use case, for example if you have multiple params you need to split at `&`